# How to recursively download specific subfolders under different folders?

Tags: wget

I need help to download a large dataset archived under a number of subfolders, which are organized under different years and days. I could not find an answer online.
The dataset is hosted at a FTP site, with the following folder structure:

- root/Year/Month/Day/dataX/
- root/Year/Month/Day/dataY/
- root/Year/Month/Day/dataZ/

I only need to download the files under dataX/ for all years under root/, and save it locally using the same folder structure.

How can I achieve this in wget? I tried different ways but didnot succeed.

edit:
I tried

```
wget -r -nH -np -I="dataX" -A *.hdf --user="USER" --password="PASS" ftp://someaddress/root/ -P mydata/
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using wget with the `-r` flag for the particular url?

Comment: tried this: `wget -r -nH -np -I="dataX" -A *.hdf --user="USER" --password="PASS" ftp://someaddress/root/ -P mydata/`

Comment: and the result?

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer I figured out myself

```
wget -r -np -nH --user USER --password PASS --accept "unique_filename_under_dataX" ftp://host_address/root/
```